# How to use Visual Studio - generated async WCF calls?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous

My `OperationContract`:

```
public List<MessageDTO> GetMessages()
        {
            List<MessageDTO> messages = new List<MessageDTO>();
            foreach (Message m in _context.Messages.ToList())
            {
                messages.Add(new MessageDTO()
                {
                    MessageID = m.MessageID,
                    Content = m.Content,
                    Date = m.Date,
                    HasAttachments = m.HasAttachments,
                    MailingListID = (int)m.MailingListID,
                    SenderID = (int)m.SenderID,
                    Subject = m.Subject
                });
            }
            return messages;
        }
```

In Service Reference configuration I checked the option "Generate asynchronous operations". How do I use the generated `GetMessagesAsync()`? In the net I found examples that use `AsyncCallback`, however I'm not familiar with that. Is there a way to use it in some friendly way like `async` and `await` keywords in .NET 4.5? If not, what should I do to invoke the method asynchronously?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you select 'Generate asynchrounous operations', you will get the 'old' behavior where you have to use callbacks.

If you want to use the new async/await syntax, you will have to select 'Generate task-based operations' (which is selected by default).

When using the default Wcf template, this will generate the following proxy code:

```
  public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetDataAsync(int value) {
      return base.Channel.GetDataAsync(value);
  }
```

As you can see, there are no more callbacks. Instead a `Task<T>` is returned.

You can use this proxy in the following way:

```
public static async Task Foo()
{
    using (ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client())
    {
        Task<string> t = client.GetDataAsync(1);
        string result = await t;
    }
}
```

You should mark the calling method with `async` and then use `await` when calling your service method.

Comment: The option "Generate task-based operations" is enabled if you are using .NET V4.5 and above.

Comment: @ManasKumar can you post that as a separate question? That will allow people to answer it.

Answer (score 3):

Your Service Reference can (if you are using .Net 4.5) be set to generate task-based async calls. (Configure Service Reference > check Allow generation of asynchronous operations > select Generate task-based operations)  These can be used like any `async` method.  Here's an example of how to use it:

```
using (var proxy = new YourServiceClient())
{
    var t1 = proxy.GetMessagesAsync();
    var t2 = proxy.GetMessagesAsync();
    //they're runnning asynchronously now!

    //let's wait for the results:
    Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
    var result1 = t1.Result;
    var result2 = t2.Result;
    Console.WriteLine(result1);
    Console.WriteLine(result2);
}
```

If your client is not using .Net 4.5,  you cannot generate service references that use `async`.  You'll have to do it the old fashioned way, using callbacks.  Here's an example:

```
static void m()
{
    var proxy = new YourServiceClient();
    proxy.GetMessagesCompleted += proxy_GetMessagesCompleted;
    proxy.GetMessagesAsync();
}

static void proxy_GetMessagesCompleted(object sender, GetMessagesCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var proxy = (IDisposable)sender;
    proxy.Dispose(); //actual code to close properly is more complex

    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // do something about this
    }

    var result = e.Result;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Note that in actual code for either of these scenarios, you shouldn't use `using` or `IDisposable.Dispose()` to clean up the client, see [Avoiding Problems with the Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx) and [this code](http://nimtug.org/blogs/damien-mcgivern/archive/2009/05/26/wcf-communicationobjectfaultedexception-quot-cannot-be-used-for-communication-because-it-is-in-the-faulted-state-quot-messagesecurityexception-quot-an-error-occurred-when-verifying-security-for-the-message-quot.aspx) to get you started into the confusing world of closing these things.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on VS2012, then you can use the `*Async` calls like this:

```
var proxy = new MyClient();
var result = await proxy.GetMessagesAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this...

```
public async Task<string> DoSomething()
{
var someProxy = new ServiceClient();

var t = someProxy.SomeMethodAsync();
await Task.WhenAny(t);

return t.Result;
```

}